# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^2}{z^2 n^2 +1}$ a meromorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across this old exam problem that I think it is a typo but I want to make sure there is not a problem with my knowledge.  The problem is show

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^2}{z^2 n^2 +1}$$

is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$.

This must be a typo since there is an essential singularity at $z=0$ (since the limit as $z$ goes to zero does not exist and is not $\infty$).  Am I wrong?   The series does seem to converge to a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$.

Comment: The limit as $z$ approaches zero does not exist since there is a sequence of poles converging to zero.

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: poles are at $z={i\over n}$ for $f_n(z)$ right? how do you conclude about es. singu?

Comment: @TaxiDriver A meromorphic function is a function is a function that is holomorphic except for a set of isolated points, which are poles. The poles here are not isolated.

Comment: @Potato Thank you,set of poles has limit point namely $0$, if set of poles has a limit point in the domain then $f$ has es. singu?

Comment: @TaxiDriver An essential singularity is a type of isolated singularity, so it is not essential either.

Comment: @TaxiDriver It depends on who is defining it, though. There is some discussion here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135458/limit-point-of-poles-is-essential-singularity-am-i-speaking-nonsense

Comment: Perhaps you can compute your sum using Poisson summation. Maple issues the following guess : it may be equal to $(\pi/2) \coth(\pi/z) - z^2/2$.